# Get Array inside Array of Object from Array of Objects - to new Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have following Array of Objects:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    Name: 'TestName',
    Age: 50,
    OtherStuff: [
      {
        MainID: 1111,
        ParrentId: 1122
      },
      {
        MainID: 2222,
        ParrentId: 2233
      }
    ],
    Animal: 'Dog'
  },
  {
    Name: 'TestName2',
    Age: 20,
    OtherStuff: [
      {
        MainID: 3333,
        ParrentId: 3344
      }
    ],
    Animal: 'Cat'
  }
]
```

I want this result:

```js
newArr = [{ MainID: 1111,
           ParrentId: 1122
         },
         { MainID: 2222,
           ParrentId: 2233
         },
         { MainID: 3333,
           ParrentId: 3344
         }]
```

How do I get every Array inside the every Object of the Array of Objects and put this in a new array of objects?

- Chris

Comment: Could you add what you've already tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one of the many ways to do so:

```js
const arr = [{ el: [1, 2] }, { el: [3] }, { el: 4 }]

console.log(arr.flatMap(e => e.el))
```

See [`array.flatMap` reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) for more information, including a warning about the `reduce` and `concat` method.

Answer (score 3):

With `reduce` method in one line.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    Name: 'TestName',
    Age: 50,
    OtherStuff: [
      {
        MainID: 1111,
        ParrentId: 1122
      },
      {
        MainID: 2222,
        ParrentId: 2233
      }
    ],
    Animal: 'Dog'
  },
  {
    Name: 'TestName2',
    Age: 20,
    OtherStuff: [
      {
        MainID: 3333,
        ParrentId: 3344
      }
    ],
    Animal: 'Cat'
  }
];

const updated = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => [...acc, ...curr.OtherStuff], []);

console.log(updated);
```

Comment: Nice one! However, I would not recommand using reduce for such a simple task. See [Is reduce() bad?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg)

Answer (score 0):

When you want to produce an array of objects from another given array of objects you use map function:

```
var newArr = arr.map(obj => {
  return obj.OtherStuff;
}).flat();
```

You combine with flat method to produce a unified array of objects instead of an array of arrays.

Comment: You can directly use flatMap, [as per my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59935297/6320039) :)

Comment: Ofcourse. I saw your answer afterwards. flatMap() is slightly more efficient than calling two separate functions, but callinf flat() after map gives you the advantage of controlling the fattening depth, in case you need it. Honestly I like the reduce() solution better than ours.

Comment: I do dislike the reduce solution: it is way less readable. See my comment and the great video linked. It is a hard one to watch for who is used to reduce (I), but a very great lesson.